# Summing for each first level index in last row of second level index in a specific column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a two level index...simplified as follows...

```
Raw Material Product Sold Quantity Consumed Total Sales
    A            B             40              100
                 C             40              200
                 D             40              300
              Summary          NaN             NaN
```

The actual df has multiple raw materials and follows the same structure as above.

My intended result is for the summary row (secondary index) to show the last observation (40) under the quantity consumed column and the sum of the observations (600) of the total sales column:

```
Raw Material Product Sold Quantity Consumed Total Sales
    A            B             40              100
                 C             40              200
                 D             40              300
              Summary          40              600
```

I have tried copying the df and summarizing to merge on (A and Summary), but the reset_index() of the df does not have A in the same row as the row with the string Summary, so the merge brings a zero value. Tried to do fillna to turn into an A, but that did not work either.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: could you add the code that created the example dataframe

Comment: Its an import from an excel file that has that structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ffill` so that the last row of `Quantity Consumed` displays the last observation as you mention, and take the `sum` of the values in `Total Sales` in order to update the value in `summary`:

```
df.iloc[:, 0] = df.iloc[:, 0].ffill()
df.iloc[[-1], -1] = df.iloc[:, -1].sum()

            Quantity Consumed  Total Sales
A B                    40.0       100.0
  C                    40.0       200.0
  D                    40.0       300.0
  Summary              40.0       600.0
```

Comment: The only thing about that is that while Summary is a fixed string for every set, A is not. for each set the raw material will have a different product code

Comment: Updated the answer, should do as you suggest now

Comment: I think I see what you mean, it has to work with a dataframe with multiple level 0 indices? Will give it a look tomorrow. Happy new year! :)

Comment: I got the quantity consumed to work (using loc). with a performance warning (indexing past lexsort depth may impact performance). But I get a key error for the total sales sum. Thanks for trying to help Yatu! Happy New Year!  :)